# Linux: how to give a user permission to restart apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, permissions

I have a script running under a non-root user which, under certain conditions, should restart apache httpd.

What would be the simplest way for me to allow the user to do that?

I'm using Ubuntu Server 8.04 LTS.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Short answer:

Using `visudo`, add the following to your sudoers file, replacing username with the proper username:

```
username ALL = /etc/init.d/apache2
```

If you want to not have to type in a password before you do this, use the following:

```
username ALL = NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/apache2
```

After this, the 'username' user can execute `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start` (or stop, restart,etc)

Long answer:
You'll likely want to setup a separate user for this if you haven't already, and then configure the /etc/sudoers file to allow a user or group to execute the command you want.

For example, to allow the user 'ben' to execute all commands as root prompting for a password, you would do the following:

```
ben ALL= ALL
```

To allow 'ben' to execute only one command (like say, `rm`), you would do the following:

```
ben ALL= /bin/rm
```

If you are running a script as a user and don't want to prompt for a password, you'll want to use the 'NOPASSWD' option like so:

```
ben ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/commandname options
```

You can do the same thing for groups by prefixing group names with a percentage sign, like so:

```
%supportstaff          ALL= NOPASSWD: /bin/commandname
```

Comment: Can `username` be restricted to a subset of parameters? Say `start` `restart` but not `stop`?

Comment: the `visudo` command does safety checks on your edits so you don't break the `sudo`/`su` command by accident: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27595/61349

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: sudo.

The call would look similar to the following: `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

Easiest is to use `visudo` to set up the /etc/sudoers file.  See `man sudoers` and `man visudo` for details.

Comment: OP said about doing it through a script- the script won't be able to enter a password so this answer won't make any sense.

Comment: @MattFletcher unless you use [NOPASSWD](http://www.ducea.com/2006/06/18/linux-tips-password-usage-in-sudo-passwd-nopasswd/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also accomplish this by writing a wrapper to apache2ctl, assigning group ownership to a web administration group and setting the suid bit. This is a less general solution than visudo, but allows custom limitations on user abilities and error checking.

I wrote this tool for my own needs and have shared it on github: https://github.com/josiahjohnston/ltd_apache2ctl