# Restart or reload Apache as "www-data" user

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, permissions, bash, sudo

I have a webhook script written in Python on my Debian/Apache2.4 server, so that it runs a deploy .sh script when pushing on GitHub. So, the script is executed by standard Apache user "www-data".
My script needs to restart or reload Apache, but the output says user doesn't have the permission to do so: `Reloading apache2 configuration (via systemctl): apache2.serviceFailed to reload apache2.service: Access denied`.
Same behaviour when doing it manually as www-data (`sudo -u www-data /etc/init.d/apache2 reload`).

So I tried to make "www-data" to have permissions to reload or restart Apache by adding the following line to my visudo : `www-data ALL = NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/apache2` (according to [this doc](https://serverfault.com/questions/69847/linux-how-to-give-a-user-permission-to-restart-apache/69854#69854)).

But it doesn't change anything. Why? Is it because Apache can't reload itself?
How can I change the permissions to do so? Or do I need the script to be executed by another user, and how?

Comment: `sudo -u www-data /etc/init.d/apache2 reload`

Is the wrong test to check the sudo permissions of the www-data user. You need the www-data user to also execute the reload command with `sudo` ... Try:

    `sudo -u www-data sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since httpd binds to port 80 and 443, which are reserved, you need root privileges to restart them. That means that the user `www-data` does not have sufficient rights to do so.

So what you need to do is to allow the user `www-data` to run this command as root. You do that by adding this line to your sudo config (or to a separate file in `/etc/sudoers.d`, if your system uses that):

```
www-data ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

Your `www-data` user will now be able to run this single command as root. You'll need to edit your script so that it contains

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

instead of just

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 reload.
```

It is possible that your system is configured to require a tty when using sudo. This is often done specifically to prevent scripts using sudo, since that is an attack vector. If that is the case, your sudoers file needs to be slightly more complex:

```
Cmnd_Alias APACHERELOAD = /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
Defaults!APACHERELOAD !requiretty
www-data ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: APACHERELOAD
```

This means that only the command `/etc/init.d/apache2 reload` can be run without a tty being required.

Comment: Thanks for this explicative and complete answer.  I just tried everything you said (including a reboot after editing sudoers), but I still get the same "access denied" error when trying to sudo -u www-data /etc/init.d/apache2 reload.

Comment: Check the systems log for error messages from sudo. Also for messages from selinux.

Comment: Sytem log says: "[system] Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.12" (uid=33 pid=3134 comm="systemctl reload apache2.service ") interface="org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager" member="ReloadUnit" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init ")". Could it be because it is launched by a different uiud than the root's uiud?

Comment: It actually works, sorry. There was an error in my sudoers files about the tty. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad it worked for you!